# How do the C compiler deal with the local var in stack during recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, stack

I write a simple binary search program and meet a problem, see my three confusions below:

- If I choose `icc -g main.c` or `icc -O0 main.c` the code return wrong answer, but if I use `icc -O2 main.c` I can have  the correct answer.
- When the code `mid = (beg + end) / 2;` be defined before the `if(beg <= end) {` the answer is right no matter what flag I use to compile it.
- I think the problem is the local var `mid` in the stack during the recursion.

Help me, thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 6
int a[MAX] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int improved_binary_search(int key, int beg, int end) {
    int mid, temp;
    //mid = (beg + end) / 2;
    if(beg <= end) {
             mid = (beg + end ) /2;
             if(a[mid] == key)
                     return mid;
             if(a[mid] < key)
                     return improved_binary_search(key, mid + 1, end);
              if(a[mid] > key)
                      return improved_binary_search(key, beg, mid - 1);
              //printf("test is %d\n", mid);
      }
      if(mid == 0)
              return 0;
      if(mid == MAX - 1)
              return MAX - 1;
      if(a[mid] < key)
              return a[mid+1] - key < key - a[mid] ? mid+1 : mid;
      if(a[mid] > key)
              return a[mid] - key < key - a[mid-1] ? mid : mid-1;
      return -1;
  }

int main(void)
{
     printf("%d\n", improved_binary_search(100, 0, MAX - 1));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: use compiler warnings, `-Wall` for icc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just declared `mid` but did not initialize it, it might happen that if the first if condition(`if(beg <= end)`)is not hit then the value of `mid` is **Indeterminate**.

That would result in **Undefined Behavior**. The behavior you see is because of this UB and not because of compiler configurations.

You should always initialize your variables to meaningful values.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you don't initialize `mid` unless `beg <= end`. The (potentially uninitialized) variable is then used in the second half of `improved_binary_search()`. This is undefined behaviour.

To fix, make sure to always initialize `mid`.